# Different results from same script

Tags: bash, sh, stdout, io-redirection

So i have this script

```
rm -f foo bar; cat foo > bar | cat bar > foo
```

I first tried running it on my machine that is running Ubuntu. I was expecting to get an error during `cat foo`, but it ran successfully. Then i tried running it on AWS Cloud9 (also runs on the same version of Ubuntu) and it gave me the error i was expecting initially.

After that i tried running the same command on different online bash compilers and each of them gave me different outputs again. The first ran successfully and the second returned 2 errors (foo is not a file, bar is not a file).

Why does different machines give different outputs from the same script?

Comment: This code has race conditions. It'll be different not just between different machines, but between different times you run it on the same machine.

Comment: (mind, it may _usually_ behave one way on one machine, and _usually_ behave a different way on a different machine, if differences between the operating systems / load profiles / caching settings / etc. impact the timing of operations; but neither behavior is more correct than the other: Both the outcomes you describe are legal for a shell interpreter operating as-specified).

Comment: @Amessihel, ...exactly. On each side of the fork the opening of the output file will happen before that side's copy of `cat` is executed, but there's no guarantee how far one side of the fork will get ahead of the other (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a race condition with multiple possible outcomes depending on the order and time processes are scheduled:

1. The shell process responsible for `cat foo > bar` gets scheduled, creates `bar`, executes `cat`, exits with an error about `foo`
2. `cat bar > foo` similarly runs, creates `foo`, reads `bar` as empty.

or

1. `cat bar > foo` runs, creates `foo`, exits with an error about `bar`
2. `cat foo > bar` runs, creates `bar`, reads `foo` as empty.

or

1. `cat foo > bar` runs, creates `bar`, gets preempted
2. `cat bar > foo` runs, creates `foo`, gets preempted
3. `cat foo` reads `foo` as empty
4. `cat bar` reads `bar` as empty

It can therefore give different results both on the same machine, and on different machines.

Comment: Caution about saying "runs". The creation of the output file happens before the copy of `cat` is started, if we want to be pedantically correct; so it wouldn't do to imply that `cat` is running before creation occurs :)

Comment: So what does the | operator do exactly? I thought ```cat bar > foo``` part should run if and only if the first part exited with an error.

Comment: @GuilhermeRaposo, you are thinking of `||` -- ref https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists

Comment: @GuilhermeRaposo I suppose you expect `|` to work as a boolean 'or' operator - but that would be a mistake. That operator is `||` and a single `|` character is a 'pipe'. It causes the output stream from the command on the left to be attached as an input stream to the command on its right. However, both `cat` commands neither produce useful output nor expect any input, so the pipe merely runs both commands simultaneously.